# Exact match with RewriteRule without regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following htacces to rewrite a precise URL (views/index.php to views/index.xml):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/views/index\.php$ /views/index.xml [L]
```

It's way too easy to forget the `\` and type `^/views/index.php$`, allowing */views/indexXphp* and */views/index/php* instead of only */views/index.php*.

Using an exact match instead of a regex is fine for my case, so would be a way to tell Apache that *for all RewriteRules below / for this RewriteRule, the dot means a . not any character so the dot is not escaped*.

So, **is there a way to have the exact match */views/index.php* without the need to escape the dot?**

Comment: Why would there be? In regex, a `.` matches any character (except newlines, in some flavors). If you want to match a `.`, just use `\.`. It's probably a waste of time to search and find ways to work around that. Even if there *is* one way, I'd recommend that you stick with traditional escaping route, so there won't be any problems further down the road.

Comment: The exact match is convenient. But, in case it matters, using a `RewriteCond` and a `RewriteRule` to implement 1 redirect is twice as slow as using a single `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Amal commented below your question that dot in regex means **any character** and since `RewriteRule` used regular expressions for URI pattern hence you will need to escape dot to make it match literal dot.

However in `mod_rewrite` rules there is way you can use `RewriteCond` to make it match literal strings **without regular expressions** using `=` sign before matching patten:

Here is an example of your translated rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/views/index.php
RewriteRule ^ /views/index.xml [L]
```

Comment: how does using `=` for literals affect encoded characters?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can match `/views/index.php` without escaping the dot.

For instance, you can use `/views/index[.]php`, where the dot lives in a character class.

Also, many regex tokens allow you to match the dot, without specifically requiring a period. For instance,

- `.` would match a period
- `[[:punct:]]` would match a period
- `\D` (not a digit) would match a period
- `\S` (not a whitespace character) would match a period
- `(?![-/])[--/]` would **only** match a period (this is a particularly perverse regex based on a small range of the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Comment: I think the OP wants to instruct Apache to treat all the `.`s in some specific RewriteRules as a literal `.`.

Comment: @AmalMurali You're probably right, but when else am I going to have a chance to use `(?![-/])[--/]` ? A real beauty who wanted to see the world. :) I have to shut down, too tired, but I'm sure by the time I get up someone else will have given the OP exactly what he wants. Catch you another time, Amal, and thanks for your coaching.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the accepted answer, the following solution worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(source)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ destination [R=301,L]
```