# How to rewrite apache request for page with no extension but ends with a dot

Tags: apache

I am having an issue where my app updater is accidentally pointing to /appcast. instead of /appcast.xml. I am trying to figure out how I can create a .htaccess file to rewrite the appcast. request to appcast.xml but have been unsuccessful and am hoping someone could led a hand.
I've tried the following with no success. Getting 404 error;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^./]+)\.$ /$1.xml [L]
```

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "\/apps\/appcast." "/apps/appcast.xml" [R=301,L]
```

as well as some other variations but I can't seem to figure it out. Those are the only directives in the htaccess as well.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476592/exact-match-with-rewriterule-without-regex for exact matching.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nic3500's link, I was able to work this out;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/apps/appcast
RewriteRule ^ /apps/appcast.xml [L]
```